# How can I move files under a folder into subfolders by using channel or goroutine

Tags: go

I have a folder which contains multiple types of files (with no subfolders in this simple case). Let's assume it contains 20000 `.raw` files and 20000 `.jpg` files. I need to move `.raw` files into `raw` folder and `.jpg` files into `jpg` folder. So I tired to use golang to solve it:

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/fs"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func CreateFolder(basePath string, folderName string) {
    os.Mkdir(basePath+"/"+folderName, 0755)
}

func MoveFile(file string, path string, folder string) {
    err := os.Rename(path+"/"+file, path+"/"+folder+"/"+file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func getInfo(a fs.FileInfo, c chan string) {
    if a.IsDir() || strings.HasPrefix(a.Name(), ".") {
        return
    } else {
        c <- a.Name()
    }
}

func dealInfo(path string, typeDict *sync.Map, c chan string) {
    for name := range c {
        sp := strings.Split(name, ".")
        suffix := sp[len(sp)-1]

        if _, ok := typeDict.Load(suffix); ok {
            MoveFile(name, path, suffix)
        } else {
            CreateFolder(path, suffix)
            MoveFile(name, path, suffix)
            typeDict.Store(suffix, 1)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(8)
    var (
        filepath = flag.String("p", "", "default self folder")
    )

    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(*filepath)
    fmt.Println("==========")
    if *filepath == "" {
        fmt.Println("No valid folder path")
        return
    } else {
        fileinfos, err := ioutil.ReadDir(*filepath)
        stime := time.Now()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        var typeDict sync.Map
        ch := make(chan string, 20)

        for _, fs := range fileinfos {
            go getInfo(fs, ch)
            go dealInfo(*filepath, &typeDict, ch)
        }
        fmt.Println(time.Since(stime))
    }
}
```

But it returns an error: `runtime: failed to create new OS thread`. I guess this is due to too much `goroutines` the script created? But I've no idea why this could happen because I think `ch := make(chan string, 20)` would limit the number of `goroutine`.

I also tried to use `wg *sync.WaitGroup`, like:

```golang
getInfo(...) // use this func to put all files info into a channel

wg.Add(20)

for i:=0; i<20; i++ {
    go dealInfo(..., &wg)  // this new dealInfo contains wg.Done()
}

wg.Wait()
```

But this will cause a `deadlock` error.

May I know the best way to move files parallel please? Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: First, please complete [the Tour](https://go.dev/tour)—among other things, it deals with the basics of concurrency. Then move on to [these Go blog series on concurrency](https://www.google.com/search?q="Go+concurrency+patterns"+site%3Ago.dev). By then, you'll probably be able to deal with your problem completely on your own. Also note that it's unreasonable to beleive that you can parallel any set of tasks by any factor. In your case, the filesystem or the storage beneath it will likely be a bottleneck. But anyway you should learn to use concurrency properly first anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work.

However the move operation depends on the Operational System and the Filesystem.

Doing it on parallel may not be optimal via NFS for instance. You must check.

The strategy of list the files, send to channels to be executed (move/rename) by some goroutines is something that I will try in this situation.

The number of goroutines (workers) can be a command line parameter.

Comment: As a new gopher, sometimes I don't know what I don't know and not quite sure about the application boundary. So any comment and orientation guidance is quite helpful to me. Thanks!

Comment: As I said, this is more SO related than Go related. Go will just call some syscalls in the end. Things like io limits and perhaps networking are more relevant IMHO